# Any proven benefits to displaying a user's name in navigation?

Tags: navigation, login

**Question:** Are there any *proven* benefits to having a "Welcome back, user", or even just "user", in the primary navigation after login?

**My Guess:**
The obvious benefit I see is that it could make the user feel as though the system they are using is tailored to them - it gives a personal touch. People also like to see and hear their own name. Lastly, it confirms that the user is logged in under the correct account.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Confirms you are logged in, and logged into the correct account (ex spouse has not changed the account to theirs)

Comment: I'd agree with Austin.  Also you are right, it makes it personal, it makes the user feel like its theirs which is powerful for retention and happiness

Comment: It also follows the first principle of the 10 [Heuristic](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/) evaluation provided by the Nielsen Norman group

Answer (score 1):

1. User knows that he is signed in
2. User knows who is he signed in as

But you don't really need to do so in mobile applications because there is usually one user per mobile phone. There are however many users per one desktop.

Google is now displaying only the first letter of your name in the circle if you aren't using google+ which is a terrible experience for families who have James, Joe and Julie in the house.